# how to write multiple overlapping underbraces

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols, underbrace

I am trying to write overlapping underbraces for this equation and I can't get the second underbrace right! Any ideas?...  [image]

Answer (score 4):

To accomplish this, I had to make the initial underbrace of zero net width.  I accomplished this by using the `\useanchorwidth{T}` feature of the `stackengine` package.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
(i\gamma^3)\underbrace{[\hat G_z, [\hat G_z, [\stackunder[-8pt]{\hat G_z}
  {\underbrace{\phantom{G_z,[G_z,G_x}}_{\hat G_u}}}_{i\hat G_y}, \hat G_x]]]+.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

By use of `\rlap` and `\phantom` you can set the first (outer) underbrace first, and then the inner.

```
\begin{displaymath}  
  (i\gamma)^3[\rlap{\ensuremath{\underbrace{\phantom{\hat{G}_z,[\underbrace{\hat{G}_z,[\hat{G}_z}_{\hat{G}_x}}}_{i\hat{G}_y}}}
  \hat{G}_z,[\underbrace{\hat{G}_z,[\hat{G}_z,\hat{G}_x]}_{\hat{G}_x}]]+
\end{displaymath}
```

[image]

Yo me it is not really clear if the outer underbrace includes the whole inner underbrace or just up to `G_z`. To show that it is the whole inner underbrace I would do something like this,

```
\begin{displaymath}  
  (i\gamma)^3[\rlap{\ensuremath{\underbrace{\phantom{\hat{G}_z,[\underbrace{\hat{G}_z,[\hat{G}_z,\hat{G}_x]}_{\hat{G}_x}}}_{i\hat{G}_y}}}
  \hat{G}_z,[\underbrace{\hat{G}_z,[\hat{G}_z,\hat{G}_x]}_{\hat{G}_x}]]+
\end{displaymath}
```

[image]